# Prove that the set is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Prove that the set

$ ( { x,y : x≠0 } ) $ with the operation $(x,y) + (a,b) = ( xa , y+b )$

and

$k (a,b) = ( a^k ,kb )$

is a vector space..

---

Well, it is obvious that the question is saying that the above set is vector space, but the problem is I don't know how to prove it, it seems that it is unusual vector space.. can someone help me to prove it?

Comment: I think you need $x>0$ not just $x\ne0$. Otherwise, what is $\sqrt2(-1,0)$ ?

Comment: I think so, however,the solution still not clear

Comment: I think you should be clearer in your question, and write that you're working with the set $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ .

Comment: Exactly it is in $R^2$

Comment: You should have a  list in your book or your notes of 8 criteria that must be met to define a vector space.  (closure under addition, existence of an identity under addition, etc.)  One by one, show that all 8 criteria have been met.

Answer (score 3):

If the set is $V=\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R$, then the map $f:\mathbb R^+ \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto (\log x, y)$ can be used to show that your definitions are just transporting the usual vector space structure of $\mathbb R^2$ to your set $V$:

$$
v_1+v_2
=(x_1,y_1) + (x_2,y_2) = (x_1 x_2, y_1+y_2)
= f^{-1}(f(v_1)+f(v_2))\\
k v= (x^k, y) = f^{-1}(kf(v))
$$

$f$ is then by construction an isomorphism of vector spaces $V \cong \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @Amsar "kinda true"? Either it is true or it is not. There are no "kindas" in mathematics in this context. And "much simpler" may depend on the beholder: for me, this is much simpler than to check all the axioms of vector space...which is what you're going to have to do if you don't see a way to deduce what you want from this nice answer.

Comment: @lhf still it is not clear my dear, could you please explain more and show how it will work?

Comment: @Amsar, see my edited answer.

Comment: can anyone try to give me a hint for proving by axioms??