# Vector Space -- Confusion

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $\mathbb{R}+$ be the set of all positive real numbers. Define the operations of addition and scalar multiplication as follows:

$u + v = u.v$ $\forall u,v \in \mathbb{R}+$

$au = u^a$ $\forall u \in \mathbb{R}+$ and real scalar $a$.

Prove that $\mathbb{R}+$ is a real vector space.

I am able to verify all the axioms for it to be vector space except inverse element axiom. Is question correct? Should it be defined over $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}+$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267186/prove-that-the-set-is-a-vector-space

Comment: Try to show where you missed the demonstration for the inverse element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inverse of $u\in\mathbb{R}^+$ will be $\frac1u$ in that vector space. Note that the zero element of that vector space is $1$, since $(\forall u\in\mathbb{R}^+):1.u=u.1=u$. So, since $u.\frac1u=\frac1u.u=1$, the inverse of $u$ is $\frac1u$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am confused about additive inverse which is defined as an element when added to "u" results into zero.

Comment: @Pankaj You seem to forget that the zero vector here is the number $1$.

Comment: I got that. I am actually confused about additive inverse. What would be the additive inverse for this vector space. (additive inverse-- an element when added to the 'x' results into zero)

Comment: @Pankaj As I wrote in my answer, the additive inverse of $u$ is $\frac1u$.

Comment: ok I got it. Thank you.